# Set a font awesome icon position

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I got this tiny code:

```
<i class="icon-plus-sign">Hello</i>
```

I can't set the font-awesome icon on the right. I tried to change the float, padding, margin, but all to no avail.

In other words, here's what I have:

[image: what I have]

Here's what I want:

[image: what I want]

**FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/UF9A3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't wrap your text inside the icon markup. Use:

```
Hello <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>
```

or

```
<i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> Hello
```

Comment: Simple answer for a simple question, I didn't see it, I searched a lot but the answer was in front of me. thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the position of the icon:

```
background:(url(../img/dash.png) 0 right no-repeat);
```

Comment: Thanks you, I will surely use it later !

Answer (score 0):

**use this**

```
<i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> hello
```

> another u can use this

```
<i class="icon-plus-sign">Hello</i>
change the position in css
```

Comment: - use always one time see this icon-plus